# Use python to get filter rule information in Revit API

Tags: revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I have started a python script that extracts the filter rule information, but can't find a way to get the information out of the "GetRuleParameters()"

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I've seen a lot of information on creating rule filters, but little on extracting the rule information.
[Here is an example for filter overrides in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492815/use-python-to-get-view-filters-for-views-in-revit-project)

Here is where I am at:

```
pfes = list(FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(ParameterFilterElement).ToElements()) for pfe in pfes:
    rps = pfe.GetRuleParameters()
    for rp in rps:
        print rp.ToString()
        el = doc.GetElement(rp)
        print el
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point it would be more helpful to print the name of the classes rather than to convert the classes to a string.  That will not get you everything though.  GetRuleParameters will return the elementID of the parameters that are used in the rule; however, the element id of built in parameters is negative.  The GetElement function doesn't seem to find parameters if they have a negative element id.  I can't find a way to get the built in parameter from the id.

```
for pfe in pfes:
    print(pfe.Name)
    rps = pfe.GetRuleParameters()


    for rp in rps:

        el = doc.GetElement(rp)

        # this will only work if the parameter used in the
        # filter is not built in
        try:
            print("\t" + el.Name)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, that's in the right direction. hmmm... I wonder if I lookup the parameters for each one.  ok...  This works.  Great!
`for pfe in pfes:
    print(pfe.Name)
    rps = pfe.GetRuleParameters()


    for rp in rps:

        el = doc.GetElement(rp)
        # this will only work if the parameter used in the
        # filter is not built in
        if el:
            for p in el.Parameters:
                print p.Definition.Name`

Comment: Here is an example of the output:
Callouts Elevations Sections_does not contain FF

Answer (score 0):

You can use RevitLookup to explore the properties and parameter values of the rule parameter elements that are returned via the list of element ids, or [research in more depth using the interactive RPS console](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/11/intimate-revit-database-exploration-with-the-python-shell.html).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  I didn't find the rules inside of the Revit Lookup tool and didn't know which properties to use in python to get more information.  Happy to try some if you have ideas.